# Weird problem with iPhone UITableView cell not un-highlighting after clicking

Tags: iphone, uitableview, highlight

I have an app I am working on, that has a table view with a few cells, and when you hit a cell, the nav controller pushes a new view. Pretty simple stuff. The problem is that when I hit on a row, the whole row highlights blue, and then remains blue all while the view is being presented by the controller, and then if I hit back to go back to the table view, the row is just still completely highlighted Even though I'm not pressing it or anything.

I have made a few apps with the table view before, and have never seen this behavior before, so I am at a loss as to what is going on. Is there some setting that I have set wrong somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to deselect cell manually (probably in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
   // Your code
   ...
}
```

Comment: Should be in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: @BoltClock, that may depend on the desired effect, but I usually do that in didDeselectRowAtIndexPath method and it is ok for me

Answer (score 2):

If your view controller is a subclass of UITableViewController, it will automatically deselect the row after you hit the back button. If you don't subclass UITableViewController, you need to call deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated: when you want it deselected.

Comment: And if you do subclass UITableViewController and override `viewWillAppear:animated:`, make sure to call the super implementation